# How can I hide scrollbar for ScrollView in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript

I've been looking back and forth on how can I hide scrollbar for a ScrollView in NativeScript Angular from the html file rather than typescript or JavaScript but I couldn't find it.

**What have I tried already:**

- This [thread](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/hide-scrollview-indicator/808) shows a way to do it by accessing the native API but it's different for both iOS and Android. I'm looking for a cross platform solution.
- I've used this [plugin](https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-swiss-army-knife) but again I'm looking for a much simpler way like some sort of a attribute `<ScrollView>` tag.

**Environment:**

**Node**: 10.16
**npm**: 6.9.0
**NativeScript**: 5.4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a way to achieve this. Use following approach:

```
<ScrollView scrollBarIndicatorVisible="false">
...
</ScrollView>
```

I hope that you found it usefull. Reference [API](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_scroll_view_.scrollview#scrollbarindicatorvisible)

---

*Followings have been tested:*

**Platforms:** Android, iOS
**Frameworks:** NativeScript - Angular, JavaScript, TypeScript
**NativeScript Version:** 3, 4, 5